# Prove that $\operatorname{SL}_4(2)$ does not contain an element of order $35$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Given $\operatorname{SL}_4(2)$, whose order is $2^6 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7$, I am interested in finding out if this group contains elements of a given order to use this to compute the structure of the subgroups, for example $35$ or $15$.

I have done the case $\operatorname{SL}_3(2)$ by explicit computation (made easier by the isomorphism with $\operatorname{PSL}_2(7)$), and I have been trying to find a general technique to solve this problem without much success

I have been trying to develop a general technique to solve problems like the one in the title, but without much success. All my successful approaches seem to be "ad hoc" for the particular group I am considering in that moment.

Comment: The first idea I got would be to study the potential characteristic polynomials. Any irreducible quartic over $\Bbb{F}_2$ is a factor of $x^{15}-1$, any irreducible cubic a factor of $x^7-1$ and any irreducible quadratic a factor of $x^3-1$. The characteristic polynomial is quartic, and a matrix is a zero of its characteristic polynomial so...

Comment: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Special_linear_group:SL(4,2) suggests that this group is just $A_8$? This isn't necessarily useful for your more general question, but seems to immediately answer all of your questions about this specific group...

Comment: ...thank you, I was not aware of this isomorphism